# How do I use integers in a Visual Basic SQL query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Not sure if I've phrased the question right but I'll elaborate.

My code is supposed to compare a percentage value calculated in the program to the respective grade boundaries in an Access database. It then outputs a letter grade (e.g. A*, A, B, C) based on the course and grade boundaries. However, my sql query for this doesn't seem to work.

Error Message: "Conversion from string "SELECT GradeLetter FROM tblGrade" to type 'Double' is not valid."

I'm sure this is a very simple fix, but I've been unable to find the correct information anywhere so far, so any help would be appreciated.

```vb
    Private Sub txtDenominator_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDenominator.TextChanged

        Dim Numerator As Integer
        Dim Denominator As Integer
        Dim Percentage As Double

        Numerator = txtNumerator.Text
        Denominator = txtDenominator.Text

        If (Numerator > 0) And (Denominator > 0) And (Numerator <= Denominator) Then
            Percentage = (Numerator / Denominator) * 100
        Else
            Percentage = 0
        End If

        MsgBox(Percentage)

        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = G:/College Database.accdb"
        con.Open()

        sql = "SELECT GradeLetter FROM tblGrades WHERE 
               CourseId = '1' AND (GradeBoundaryLow <= " + Percentage + ")
               AND (GradeBoundaryHigh >= " + Percentage + ")"

        MsgBox(sql)

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds2, "Grades")

        con.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Code is much easier to deal with and understand that a picture.

Comment: Providing sample data and desired output as text tables can also be helpful. And you can delete the image now. It's just a distraction.

Comment: If tblGrades has student grade results, why would that table also have grade boundary data? Again, provide sample raw data and desired output.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict in Project Properties on the Compile tab. Fix the errors this points out and edit the code in you question.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in comments, the very first thing you need to do is turn on Option Strict for this project in Project Properties and for all future projects in Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VB Defaults.

You cannot depend on a user entering what you wish in a `TextBox`. Use the `.TryParse` method to validate.

**Always** use parameters to avoid sql injection and assure the correct type is being sent to the database. I am assuming the `CourseId` is a numeric type in the database. Don't surround numbers with quotes.

Database objects need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us. In this case both the connection and the command are included in the same `Using` block. Note the comma at the end of the first line of the `Using`.

You can pass the the connection string directly to the constructor of the  connection and the `CommandText` and `Connection` to the constructor of the `Command`.

We need 2 parameters even though the values are the same. OleDb considers only the position of the parameters, not the names. I use names instead of "?" for readability. The position of the parameter in the sql string must match the order that the parameters are added to the parameters collection.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execute...` and close it as soon as possible with the `End Using`.

Since you are only retrieving a single piece of data, you can use `.ExecuteScalar`. This returns an `Object` so you must call `.ToString` to make the assignment to `GradeLetter`.

```
Private Sub txtDenominator_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDenominator.TextChanged
    Dim Numerator As Integer
    Dim Denominator As Integer
    Dim Percentage As Double
    If Not Integer.TryParse(txtNumerator.Text, Numerator) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in Numerator")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Integer.TryParse(txtDenominator.Text, Denominator) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Denominator")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (Numerator > 0) And (Denominator > 0) And (Numerator <= Denominator) Then
        Percentage = (Numerator / Denominator) * 100
    Else
        Percentage = 0
    End If
    Dim GradeLetter As String = ""
    Dim Sql = "SELECT GradeLetter FROM tblGrades 
                WHERE CourseId = 1 
                AND GradeBoundaryLow <= @Percentage
                AND (GradeBoundaryHigh >= @Percentage2;"
    Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = G:/College Database.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Percentage", OleDbType.Double).Value = Percentage
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Percentage2", OleDbType.Double).Value = Percentage
        con.Open()
        GradeLetter = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show($"The grade letter for {Percentage:N2}% is {GradeLetter}")
End Sub
```

Comment: Kudos for being the only one to bestow some anti sql injection hacking advice

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are getting is because `sql` is a string and `percentage is a double.

Your quick fix is to convert `percentage` to string with `percentage.tostring()`.

Comment: Actually, the quick fix is to use the vb "string concat" operator `&` not the "usually numeric addition but will concat if both sides are strings" operator `+`

Answer (score 1):

You have Option Strict Off, and used `+` to “add” the objects together.  And `Percentage` is a double, combine these three facts and your code is effectively:

```vb
sql = CDbl("SELECT GradeLetter FROM tblGrades WHERE 
               CourseId = '1' AND (GradeBoundaryLow <= ") + Percentage + 
               Cdbl(")
               AND (GradeBoundaryHigh >= ") + Percentage + CDbl(")")
```

Which of course doesn’t work.  If you turn Option Strict On, the compiler will tell you about this, but you’ll still have fix it yourself.

The easiest way to fix it is to use `&` instead of `+`, the more correct way is to use string interpolation or parameters.  Given that percentage is a double (so no danger of sql injection), I would use string interpolation, like so…

```vb
sql = $"SELECT GradeLetter 
        FROM tblGrades 
        WHERE CourseId = '1' AND (GradeBoundaryLow <= {Percentage}
               AND (GradeBoundaryHigh >= {Percentage}"
```

PS unless you need the performance, I would recommend using Decimal for your percentage.

Comment: Yes, though I'd prefer a solution that teaches about avoiding sql injection hacking, even though it couldn't occur here

Comment: @CaiusJard: I thought about that, but wanted to explain what is going on more than showing ways to fix something that isn’t a problem in this particular case.

Comment: Agree, though worth pointing out that using parameters would also fix the problem, as it;s essentially caused by not parameterizing :D

Answer (score 0):

If fields are number type, don't surround parameter with apostrophes. Probably need line continuation character with each line part enclosed in quotes. Try BETWEEN AND syntax. Consider:

```
sql = "SELECT GradeLetter FROM tblGrades " & _
      "WHERE CourseId = 1 AND " & Percentage & " BETWEEN GradeBoundaryLow AND GradeBoundaryHigh"
```

Regarding string concatenation characters, review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/concatenation-operators

Comment: Yes, though I'd prefer a solution that teaches about avoiding sql injection hacking, even though it couldn't occur here